# How to declare function within jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have the following where if you click on one of the list items, a JavaScript function will be called. This should run the jQuery below to hide/show an element.

```
div#user-box
  ul
    li#dashboard(href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1')")
      a Dashboard
    li#settings(href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2')")
      a Settings
  div(class='newboxes' id='newboxes1')
    p Dashboard
  div(class='newboxes' id='newboxes2')
    p Account ID:
```

I tried this and but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showonlyone = function(thechosenone) {
$('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
   $(this).show(200)}
   else {
   $(this).hide(600);
   }
})
}
})
```

The functionality must be working, it's just that the function must not be called when clicking on the list items.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V4DTZ/ ..... Like This

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the function is out of scope, it should work if you move the function outside of `$(document).ready` like this.

```js
  function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).show(200)}
    else {
      $(this).hide(600);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user-box">
  <ul>
    <li id="dashboard">
      <a href="#" onclick="showonlyone('newboxes1')">Dashboard</a>
     </li>
     <li id="settings">
      <a href="#" onclick="showonlyone('newboxes2')">Settings</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" hidden="hidden">
  dashboard
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" hidden="hidden">
  settings
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help =)

Answer (score 0):

**Like This ????**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    $('.newboxes').on('click', function(){
    $('.div_newboxes').hide(600);
        var div_id = "#div_" + $(this).prop('id');
        $(div_id).show(200);
    })
}(jQuery))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a class="newboxes" href="#" id="newboxes1">show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div  class ="div_newboxes" id="div_newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a class="newboxes" href="#" id="newboxes2" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div  class ="div_newboxes" id="div_newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a class="newboxes" href="#" id="newboxes3" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div  class ="div_newboxes" id="div_newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: div_newboxes is outside of that scope by one level.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: hmm wait... you want this in One Level